# "RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference" Recyclerview into fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I've a tabbed activity, I want to show in the first fragment (Tab1History) a Recyclerview and Cardview. I've created a XML file for CardView, and in the fragment XML I've insert the Recyclerview. I've also created the adapter:

```
public class CespiteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CespiteAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private List<CespiteOgg> cespiteOggList;
    private Context context;

public CespiteAdapter(List<CespiteOgg> cespiteOggList, Context context) {
    this.cespiteOggList = cespiteOggList;
    this.context = context;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public CardView cv;
    public TextView txtNumInventario;
    public TextView txtNomeCespite;
    public TextView txtDtCatalogazione;
    public TextView txtAula;
    public TextView txtNomeUser;


    ViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super (itemView);
        //cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        txtNumInventario = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNumeroInventario);
        txtNomeCespite = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeCespite);
        txtDtCatalogazione = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDataCatalogazione);
        txtAula = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAula);
        txtNomeUser= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeUser);

    }
}



@Override
public CespiteAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    View cespiteView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cespite_card_view, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(cespiteView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    CespiteOgg cespiteOgg = cespiteOggList.get(position);

    holder.txtNumInventario.setText(cespiteOgg.getNumInventario());
    holder.txtNomeCespite.setText(cespiteOgg.getNomeCespite());
    holder.txtDtCatalogazione.setText(cespiteOgg.getDtCatalogazione().toString());
    holder.txtAula.setText(cespiteOgg.getAula());
    holder.txtNomeUser.setText(cespiteOgg.getNomeUser());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return cespiteOggList.size();
}
}
```

And here's the fragment:

```
 public class Tab1History extends Fragment
{



 private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

private List<CespiteOgg> cespiteOggList;
private Date location;
Date date = new Date(location.getTime());



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cespite_card_view, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);//every item of the RecyclerView has a fix size
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    cespiteOggList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
    {
        CespiteOgg cespiteOgg = new CespiteOgg("heading"+(i+1), "Lorem ipsum", date, "sdjijsad", "jdkjd");

        cespiteOggList.add(cespiteOgg);

    }

    adapter = new CespiteAdapter(cespiteOggList, getContext());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            return rootView;
}
}
```

And it's the stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.arslan.qrcode, PID: 14311
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Here's cespite_card_view XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/cardView">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCespite"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/thebigger" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNumeroInventario"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgCespite"
        android:text="text1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNomeCespite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtNumeroInventario"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgCespite"
        android:text="text2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDataCatalogazione"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtNomeCespite"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgCespite"
        android:text="text3" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAula"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDataCatalogazione"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgCespite"
        android:text="text4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNomeUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtAula"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgCespite"
        android:text="text5" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And it's the fragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.arslan.qrcode.Main"
android:layout_weight="1"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your layout named cespite_card_view

Comment: You can not call `getView()` within onCreateView... The view isn't created yet!

Comment: They presumably fixed that, actually, from comments on the last question they posted about this. That wouldn't be the stack trace they'd get if they didn't.

Comment: You're likely inflating the wrong layout for the `Fragment`. You're using `cespite_card_view` for both the `Adapter` and `Fragment`.

Comment: @BatuhanCoşkun added the layout.

Comment: @MikeM. nope, I think it's the correct layout

Comment: No, it's not. There's no `RecyclerView` in that layout. What did you expect `findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView)` to find? It's only going to look in the `View` you're inflating there, which is `cespite_card_view`.

Comment: @MikeM. Oh I think I understand, sow how can I solve?

Comment: In the `View rootView = inflater.inflate(...);` line, change the `R.layout` to the layout that has your `RecyclerView` in it; the `Fragment` layout you mentioned.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank u man.. solved. Silly error..

Answer (score 5):

Change this line :

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
```

To this:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
```

Also, you are using the same layout for your `RecyclerView.Adapter` and your `Fragment` in this line:

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cespite_card_view, container, false);
```

You should have a layout file for your fragment that contains your `RecyclerView` widget inside it, like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="#e9e9e9 />
```

Comment: Keeps crashing..

Comment: check the edited answer now.

Comment: yeah in the fragment layout I've insert the RecyclerView widget, but doesn't work..

Comment: there is a lot of bugs inyour code , your recycler view ID is wrong and you are using the wrong layout, what is the name of the layout file where you have the recyclerview widget/

Comment: Layout file name is "tab1history.xml"

Comment: Solved.. Was inflating the wrong layout file..

Comment: yes, that's what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Change `getView()` into `rootView`

`getView` - Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)), if provided.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cespite_card_view, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);//every item of the RecyclerView has a fix size
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    cespiteOggList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
    {
        CespiteOgg cespiteOgg = new CespiteOgg("heading"+(i+1), "Lorem ipsum", date, "sdjijsad", "jdkjd");

        cespiteOggList.add(cespiteOgg);

    }

    adapter = new CespiteAdapter(cespiteOggList, getContext());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Keeps crashing..

Comment: @Arstek you didn't set any id for the RecyclerView. please check it

Comment: No I've set, but I was inflating the wrong layout file, solved

Answer (score 0):

You should find your view from inflated view.
Use:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
```

instead of:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Keeps crashing..